# Can't start a download in Android WebView API 19+ some reason

Tags: android, webview

I have a webview in my project (running Android 5.0 API 19+) and I go to click on a link that should start a download and nothing happens.  When i go to the link using Chrome Browser that came on the phone it works perfectly fine, however in the webview nothing happens.

**EDIT Added for clerification**

```
<a ng-click="data.downloadDataSet()" class="button">Download Data</a>
```

The response for the "file download" should come back starting with..

```
data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,
```

it pushes back the file as a data:text parse.  I'm trying to get the response from when I click on the link but again nothing happens.  Nothing gets fired, none of my Log.d or Log.i below or anything.

I have these settings set...

```
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new subWebViewClient());

    webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                    long contentLength) {
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                    Uri.parse(url));
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "download");
            Log.i("here", "here");

        }
    });
```

I also have...

```
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.d(TAG, "***** OverrideUrlLoading *****" + "   " + url);
        isRedirected = true;
        webView.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        Log.d(TAG, "***** PageStarted *****" + "   " + url);
        if (!isRedirected) {
            Log.d(TAG, "***** PageStarted *****" + "   " + url);
        }
        isRedirected = false;
    }
```

But nothing happens? I don't get anything to fire or anything anywhere...

In AndroidManifest.xml i also have...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You build the download request but never fire it(enqueue)...  Read the documentation how to do this.

Comment: What do you mean I never fire it?  I am manually clicking on the link and nothing is happening.  I even have it Log set as you see above, that doesn't even fire.

Comment: *What do you mean I never fire it?* explanation is in parenthesis ... with next statment ist should give an answer(after some small reading, reasearch on doc site) ...edit:  so even `Log.i("here", "here");` is not called?

Comment: Nope, not even that happens.  Nothing happens at all thats the problem I'm having.  I'm clicking on the WebView the link and nothing returns at all.  None of those Log.i or Log.d or anything fires from anything.  not from the DownloadListener, not the OverrideURLLoading nothing

Comment: lol ... but this <a> has no href but it runs some javascript `data.downloadDataSet()` ...

Comment: but a download / data is sent back there should be somethign that is fired.  When I do this in Google Chrome browser directly, the file downloads normally.  I assumed that a DownloadEvent would fire in the WebView but nothing is happening.  Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: ok this will be kind of programming by permutation by try to change schema from `data` to fx `x-data`(or any other) check if it hit shouldOverrideUrlLoading ... also how you do "file download" ... i mean somthing like `window.location = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,';` or what ?

Comment: so changing the Element manually into something else then check to see if it hits OverrideUrl?  Can you toss me a quick example on what you think should work?  Would be really helpful in pointing me in the right direction I been scratching at this for days now.  Honestly you kind of lost me on the "data to fx x-data"

Comment: with `webView.loadData("<a onclick=\"window.open('data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,asdasdsadsdsdasdsa');\" href=\"javascript:void(0)\"> aasdadsd</a>",
                "text/html", "utf-8");` if i click on the link it gives me output `TAG: ***** OverrideUrlLoading *****   data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,asdasdsadsdsdasdsa` ... on 6.0 and 2.3.7 emulator

Comment: This won't work for me because i don't know the data:text/csv information of course because this is returned WHEN the data.downloadDataSet() is clicked.  data.downloadDataSet() appears to be AngularJS or NodeJS, so it has to do something in background before returning file data.  Similar to a PHP response when the response is a forced file.